# How to center 3 - 4 glwords?

Tags: xetex, expex

```
\documentclass{article} % xelatex engine
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}
\begingl
\centering % just right-align
\gla This is a test//
\glb This is a test//
\endgl
\end{document}
```

Comment: The ExPex glossing macros can do a lot, and as such are not really designed for being centred. If this is a one-off use, you would be better simply using a `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 2):

I would not use ExPex for this task, unless you have very complex glossing needs which can only be served by it. But in that case, I don't quite see how the centring that you are looking for is a sensible thing to do.

### Solution using `cgloss4e`

Instead you can use the glossing macros provided by the `gb4e` package. You can load the glossing macros by themselves using the `cgloss4e` package, which will not interfere with ExPex if you are using it for other purposes. You can't use both ExPex and `gb4e` together without some extra adaptation, since both packages provide an `\ex` command.

In the following example I've created a command `\clg` which centres its content using the `varwidth` package, which provides a `minipage` environment that fits to the natural width of the contents.

The `cgloss4e` package is loaded by `gb4e`. You can check its documentation for details on how it works. I've loaded the `geometry` package with the `showframe` option just to show the centring.

```
\documentclass{article} % xelatex engine
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{cgloss4e}
\usepackage{varwidth}

\newcommand{\cgl}[1]{%
\centering
\begin{varwidth}[t]{\linewidth}{#1}\end{varwidth}%
}

\begin{document}
\cgl{
\gll Le livre est sur la table.\\
     The book is on the table\\
     }
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

### A solution using ExPex

There is a way to do this with ExPex with a slightly more complicated syntax.  This is a version of Fran's solution but with a calculation of the spacing more automatically. Thanks also to David Carlisle for the code to count the spaces in the argument. This count is used to calculate the extra space to add.

```
\documentclass{article} % xelatex engine
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{expex}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\cgllen}

% code from David Carlisle to count spaces in an argument
\def\countspc#1{\xspc0#1 \xspc}
\def\xspc#1#2 #3{%
 \ifx\xspc#3%
   \the#1%
  \else
   \afterfi
   \xspc{\numexpr#1+1\relax}%
  \fi}
\def\afterfi#1\fi{\fi#1}

% Command takes two arguments: the longest line of the gloss (\gla or \glb
% and then the  \begingl ... \endgl environment
\newcommand{\expexcgl}[2]{%
\setlength{\cgllen}{\widthof{#1}+\countspc{#1}\lingglspace*\real{.5}}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\cgllen}%
#2
\end{minipage}}

\begin{document}

\expexcgl{Le livre est sur la table que j’ai achetée.}
{\begingl
\gla Le livre est sur la table que j’ai achetée.//
\glb The book is on the table that I-have bought//
\endgl
}

\expexcgl{Le livre est sur la grande table.}
{\begingl
\gla Le livre est sur la grande table.//
\glb The book is on the big  table//
\endgl
}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of ExPex code]

Comment: Thank you! Powerfull! But notetheless I should choose what line is wider - gla or glb (in expex version) - otherwise if the chosed one would be shorter - centering breaks.

Comment: @Ivi Yes, I'm afraid that's true.  There's no real way around that. I haven't found a way to measure the natural width of the whole `\begingl ... \endgl` environment.

Answer (score 0):

Using a centered minipage only slightly wider that the text, the text still is not really centered, but the difference will be hardly noticeable:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex,calc}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{\widthof{This is a test}+2pt}
\begingl
\gla This is a test//
\glb This is a test//
\endgl
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Notetheless I agree with Alan Munn that make a small table is a lot simpler that force this special environment.

Comment: This doesn't really centre the content though.

Comment: @AlanMunn Oppss... I do dot I did not realize that (a) I was using `\hfill` instead of  `\hfil` and (b)  the text is leftfar from the  the center of the box.  Updating in 4,3,2 ....

Comment: This won't really work in generality, since you need to measure the width of the `gl` environment itself; there's no guarantee that the `\gla` and `\glb` lines will be of equal length.

Comment: Thank you for very usefull answers! \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c}
\begingl
\gla Using a centered minipage//
\glb Using a centered minipage//
\endgl
\end{tabular}
\end{document} % Am I right, that this also does not center?

Comment: @Ivi When we say use a `tabular` environment, we mean do not use ExPex to line up the words; put them in a `tabular` instead.

Comment: @AlanMunn The real problem is that with others sentences ( for some glue, I guess)  will need some more extra space that +2pt, and this type of fine tuning based in trial and error is annoying, but  I do not see problem with unequal  `\gla` and `\glb` except that you must choose the longer for `\widthof`.